# How to format Cells like accounting except using Percentage sign

Tags: formatting

I am trying to create a hybrid format between Accounting and Percentage.

My cell value I am going to format contains a percentage. I would like to move the % Sign to left justified in the cell as it would be if it were formatted with Accounting.

I also want `0.00%` values to be displayed as `%  -`     as it would with accounting

[Example of Accounting Format (left) and Percentage Format (right). I would like to make a hybrid format per se.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNdpc.png)

Comment: [Read this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/number-format-codes-5026bbd6-04bc-48cd-bf33-80f18b4eae68) and take a stab at it. Post how far you get.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Post has been updated to include more specifics.

Answer (score 0):

I have found my solution.

```
_(%* #,##0.00_);_(%* (#,##0.00);_(%* "-"??_);_(@_)
```

I was able to use the accounting format as a basis.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).